Django Form Submission Not Triggering `create_cancel` View
Problem Description:
I am implementing an order cancellation feature in my Django application. The process involves displaying a cancellation form (cancel-order.html) using the cancel_order view and processing the form submission with the create_cancel view to update the product_status of CartOrder and CartOrderItems.
However, the issue is that the create_cancel view is not being triggered when the form is submitted. No success or error messages are displayed, and no updates are made to the database.
Views:
Here are the relevant views:
def cancel_order(request, oid):
    sub_category = SubCategory.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.prefetch_related('subcategories').order_by('?')[:4]
    wishlist = wishlist_model.objects.filter(user=request.user) if request.user.is_authenticated else None
    nav_category = Category.objects.filter(special_category=True).prefetch_related('subcategories').order_by('?')[:4]
    order = CartOrder.objects.get(user=request.user, id=oid)
    products = CartOrderItems.objects.filter(order=order)

    # Calculate discounts for each product
    total_old_price = 0
    total_price = 0

    for item in products:
        product = item.product  # Assuming a ForeignKey from CartOrderItems to Product
        qty = item.qty  # Assuming a quantity field in CartOrderItems
        total_old_price += (product.old_price or 0) * qty
        total_price += (product.price or 0) * qty

    # Calculate total discount percentage
    if total_old_price > 0:  # Prevent division by zero
        discount_percentage = ((total_old_price - total_price) / total_old_price) * 100
    else:
        discount_percentage = 0

    context = {
        "order": order,
        "products": products,
        "sub_category": sub_category,
        "categories": categories,
        "wishlist": wishlist,
        "nav_category": nav_category,
        "discount_percentage": round(discount_percentage, 2),  # Round to 2 decimal places
    }

    return render(request, 'core/cancel-order.html', context)


def create_cancel(request, oid):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user

        # Fetch POST data
        reason = request.POST.get('reason')
        description = request.POST.get('description')

        try:
            # Fetch the CartOrder instance
            order_cancel = get_object_or_404(CartOrder, id=oid, user=user)
            order_cancel.product_status = "cancelled"
            order_cancel.save()

            # Fetch related CartOrderItems instances
            order_items = CartOrderItems.objects.filter(order=order_cancel)
            for item in order_items:
                item.product_status = "cancelled"
                item.save()

            # Log the reason and description (if you want to save this somewhere)
            # Example: save to a cancellation model (optional)
            # CancellationReason.objects.create(order=order_cancel, reason=reason, description=description)

            messages.success(request, "Order successfully cancelled.")

        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, f"An error occurred: {e}")

        return redirect("core:dashboard")
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Invalid request method.")
        return redirect("core:dashboard")

Template:
Here is the form in the cancel-order.html template:
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static './assets/images/logo/favicon.ico'  %}" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Cancel Order</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #f8f9fa;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            align-items: flex-start; /* Align items at the top to allow vertical scrolling */
            min-height: 100vh;/* Ensure the body covers the viewport */
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .cancel-order-container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-start;
            gap: 20px;
            background: #ffffff;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 800px;
            padding: 30px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .cancel-order-container img {
            max-width: 150px;
            height: auto;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .cancel-order-form {
            flex: 1;
        }

        .cancel-order-form h2 {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            color: #343a40;
        }

        .form-group {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        .form-group label {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            color: #495057;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .form-group input, .form-group select, .form-group textarea {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ced4da;
            border-radius: 4px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .form-group textarea {
            resize: vertical;
            min-height: 100px;
        }

        .form-actions {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .btn {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        }

        .btn-cancel {
            background-color: #dc3545;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .btn-cancel:hover {
            background-color: #c82333;
        }

        .btn-back {
            background-color: #6c757d;
            color: #ffffff;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        .btn-back:hover {
            background-color: #5a6268;
        }

        .modal {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            z-index: 1000;
        }

        .modal-content {
            background: #ffffff;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            text-align: center;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .modal-content p {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #343a40;
        }

        .modal-buttons {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            gap: 10px;
        }

        @media (max-width: 576px) {
            .cancel-order-container {
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
            }

            .cancel-order-container img {
                max-width: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            .cancel-order-form {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .btn {
                width: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            .btn-back {
                margin-right: 0;
            }

            .form-actions {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function showConfirmationModal(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const modal = document.getElementById('confirmation-modal');
            modal.style.display = 'flex';
        }

        function hideModal() {
            const modal = document.getElementById('confirmation-modal');
            modal.style.display = 'none';
        }

        function confirmAndSubmit() {
            document.querySelector('.cancel-order-form').submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cancel-order-container">
        <img src="{{order.images}}" alt="Product Image">
        <form class="cancel-order-form" action="{% url 'core:create_cancel' oid=order.id %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="showConfirmationModal(event)" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h2>Cancel Your Order</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="order-number">Order Number</label>
                <input type="text" id="order-number" name="order-number" value="{{order.oid}}" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="product-name">Product Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="product-name" name="product-name" value="{{order.title}}" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="product-price">Product Price</label>
                <input type="text" id="product-price" name="product-price" value="{{order.price}}" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="product-price">Product Old Price</label>
                <input type="text" id="product-price" name="product-price" value="{{order.old_price}}" readonly>
            </div>
            {% if order.size %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="product-price">Product Size</label>
                <input type="text" id="product-price" name="product-price" value="{{order.size}}" readonly>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            <!-- <div class="form-group">
                <label for="product-price">Product Color</label>
                <input type="text" id="product-price" name="product-price" value="{{order.color}}" readonly>
            </div> -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="reason">Reason for Cancellation</label>
                <select id="reason" name="reason" required>
                    <option value="">Select a reason</option>
                    <option value="delay">Order Delay</option>
                    <option value="changed_mind">Changed My Mind</option>
                    <option value="found_cheaper">Found a Cheaper Option</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comments">Additional Comments</label>
                <textarea id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Provide additional details (optional)"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-back" onclick="history.back()">Go Back</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-cancel">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="confirmation-modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>Are you sure to cancel the order? You are saving {{ discount_percentage }}% on this order.</p>
            <div class="modal-buttons">
                <button class="btn btn-back" onclick="hideModal()">No</button>
                <button class="btn btn-cancel" onclick="confirmAndSubmit()">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Models:
Here are the CartOrder and CartOrderItems models:
STATUS_CHOICE = (
    ("processing", "Processing"),
    ("shipped", "Shipped"),
    ("out_for_delivery", "Out for delivery"),
    ("delivered", "Delivered"),
    ("return_accepted", "Return Accepted"),
    ("pick_up", "Pick Up"),
    ("refund_completed", "Refund Completed"),
    ("cancelled", "Cancelled"),
)

class CartOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    oid = ShortUUIDField(length=10, max_length=100, prefix="oid", alphabet="1234567890")
    product_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, default="processing")
    # Other fields...

class CartOrderItems(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(CartOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="items")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    product_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, default="processing")
    # Other fields...

URLs:
Here are the URL patterns:
path("cancel_order/<int:oid>", cancel_order, name="cancel_order"),
path("create_cancel/<int:oid>", create_cancel, name="create_cancel"),

Observed Behavior:

The cancel-order.html form renders correctly with the action URL pointing to the create_cancel view.
When submitting the form, the create_cancel view is not triggered.
No success or error messages are displayed.
No changes are made to the product_status fields in the database.

Expected Behavior:
When the form is submitted, the create_cancel view should be triggered, and it should update the product_status fields for the CartOrder and associated CartOrderItems. Success or error messages should be displayed accordingly.
Questions:

What could be causing the create_cancel view to not trigger upon form submission?
Are there any common issues with form submission or URL resolution in Django that I might be overlooking?
Could this be related to how the oid parameter is being passed in the URL or how the POST request is handled?


"When submitting the form, the create_cancel view is not triggered." ok, what does happen when you submit your form? Does some other view run? Does the server show any logs suggesting that the browser even made a request? Does the browser show anything in the console / network pane of the devtools?

No Log is clear It is not throwing any error and also not redirecting to dashboard as per my view. I also tried to re-submitting the form after clearing the cache from network tab but no changes...

Ok. I found the problem
I did the mistake in URLs
My views:
def cancel_order(request, oid):
    sub_category = SubCategory.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.prefetch_related('subcategories').order_by('?')[:4]
    wishlist = wishlist_model.objects.filter(user=request.user) if request.user.is_authenticated else None
    nav_category = Category.objects.filter(special_category=True).prefetch_related('subcategories').order_by('?')[:4]
    order = CartOrder.objects.get(user=request.user, id=oid)
    products = CartOrderItems.objects.filter(order=order)

    # Calculate discounts for each product
    total_old_price = 0
    total_price = 0

    for item in products:
        product = item.product  # Assuming a ForeignKey from CartOrderItems to Product
        qty = item.qty  # Assuming a quantity field in CartOrderItems
        total_old_price += (product.old_price or 0) * qty
        total_price += (product.price or 0) * qty

    # Calculate total discount percentage
    if total_old_price > 0:  # Prevent division by zero
        discount_percentage = ((total_old_price - total_price) / total_old_price) * 100
    else:
        discount_percentage = 0

    context = {
        "order": order,
        "products": products,
        "sub_category": sub_category,
        "categories": categories,
        "wishlist": wishlist,
        "nav_category": nav_category,
        "discount_percentage": round(discount_percentage, 2),  # Round to 2 decimal places
    }

    return render(request, 'core/cancel-order.html', context)


def create_cancel(request, oid):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user

        # Fetch POST data
        reason = request.POST.get('reason')
        description = request.POST.get('description')

        try:
            # Fetch the CartOrder instance
            order_cancel = get_object_or_404(CartOrder, id=oid, user=user)
            order_cancel.product_status = "cancelled"
            order_cancel.save()

            # Fetch related CartOrderItems instances
            order_items = CartOrderItems.objects.filter(order=order_cancel)
            for item in order_items:
                item.product_status = "cancelled"
                item.save()

            # Log the reason and description (if you want to save this somewhere)
            # Example: save to a cancellation model (optional)
            # CancellationReason.objects.create(order=order_cancel, reason=reason, description=description)

            messages.success(request, "Order successfully cancelled.")

        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, f"An error occurred: {e}")

        return redirect("core:dashboard")
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Invalid request method.")
        return redirect("core:dashboard")

and in urls.py:
path("cancel_order/<int:oid>", cancel_order, name="cancel_order"),
path("create_cancel/<int:oid>", create_cancel, name="create_cancel"),

previously I was triggering same view cancel_order instade of create_cancel
